# Getting unicode character name in old Android API

Tags: java, android, unicode

I'm trying to get the textual representation of a unicode Character on Android, API Level 10.

I know, that at API Level 19, I could use [Character.getName()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Character.html#getName%28int%29), but my API Level does not allow for that.

Are there any easy methods to get that name or do I have to use a copy of http://www.unicode.org/Public/6.0.0/ucd/UnicodeData.txt and parse that? (I would prefer not to add >1MB of data to my app)